# Image to show when users Like a product on my site - NOT og: tag

Tags: facebook, e-commerce, facebook-like

From what I understand, the `og:image` is part of meta tags that appear in the `<head>` section of the page.

Our ecommerce package can show multiple products on one page. I want the Like button on EACH product, so when a user clicks the Like button, it will post that PRODUCT on their wall, along with that individual product image. Since the meta tags are generated at the top in the `<head>`, before the products are pulled and displayed on the page, I have no way to set up my `og:image` meta tag to be appropriate for that product.

I have tried using the Like button code like this:

```
<div class="fb-like"
     data-href="http://kaysbeadedjewelry.com/asccustompages/products.asp?productID=29"
     data-send="false"
     data-width="30"
     data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

but it displays the wrong image on the page. I have tried this on different sites and cannot figure out how it decides which image to grab and display. It seems to grab a random image from the page. Each client's site I've tried this on grabs different images from different locations on the page.

I have also tried using the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=http://kaysbeadedjewelry.com/asccustompages/products.asp?productID=29"
        scrolling="no"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

and it also gives me the same issue.

How do I get Facebook to show the actual product image and not some random one?

Answer (score 0):

you would set the og: tags on each individual products own page, then on the summary page where you want your fb button, make the url of the like button be the url of the product page. Then the like will be on the product itself, not the summary page.

Make sure you are using the [linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://kaysbeadedjewelry.com/asccustompages/products.asp?productID=29) to check what og tags facebook is getting for each of your pages